Custom decoding in Elasticsearch
I want to encode my data before putting it into Elasticsearch using dictionary encoding. The data is quite tabular, singular values, a lot of duplicates in columns, so dictionary encoding is a good option.
Could you please give a piece of advice - is it possible to embed decoding algorithm in Elastic? So that queries would be encoded and matches would decode using dictionaries? From where to start - any information is welcomed.
I encoded data and loaded into Elasticsearch. Satisfied with the result but next requirement/request is to embed encoding of queries and decoding of results. Is it possible?

If you want to manipulate the data before you ingest it into the Elasticsearch, I strongly recommend using Logstash, which is another leg of elk (elasticsearch, logstash, kibana).
There are 3 sections in it.
Input -> Decide which way and data type you want to ingest.
Filter -> Manipulate the data
Output -> Create index, set index lifecycle policy etc.
All of three have different plugins.
Input Plugins,
Filter Plugins,
Output Plugins
